# Openshift 3 mysql.user table is damaged. please run mysql_upgrade openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

#### Issue

When starting a mysql deployment on OpenShift V3 I get the following exception:

```
mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade
```

I cannot run `mysql_upgrade` as pod isn't ready.

#### Questions

I have the following questions

- How can I fix this, or
- How can I backup the data

Answer (score 1):

If the pod won't start, you can mount the volume with your data to another pod and download (`oc rsync`, [interactive tutorial here](https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/transferring-files/)) what you had mounted in the database pod under `/var/lib/mysql/data/`. Then, you can try recovering the data from that.

---

Generally, this could happen if you process an older database dump `sql` script (created using `mysqldump`) on a newer MySQL version. In that case, chances are the `root` user was removed from the table too (if it was not in the old database). If you created such a dump, still have the older dump, and it's *"good enough"*, you should be able to proceed as follows to import the original data again and prevent this situation:

1. Create a backup copy of the database dump that you have previously created using `mysqldump` from the older MySQL database version, so that you can always get back to it, if things go south.
2. Edit the database dump `sql` file and remove all the content that manipulates the `mysql.user` table; that is, delete lines under the `-- Table structure for table 'user'` and `-- Dumping data for table 'user'` sections and save the modified file. I assume here that you have your user and password specified in environment variables, in the MySQL deployment configuration).
3. Scale down your database pod to 0 replicas.
4. Delete your mysql persistent volume claim; this will delete the database that you have hopefully downloaded after mounting the volume to another pod, as mentioned above.
5. Recreate the PVC, under the same name.
6. Scale up your MySQL pod to one replica. That will initialize the database and create a user as per the environment variables .
7. Copy the modified `sql` dump file created in step 2 (that is, the one not affecting the `mysql.user` table) to the database pod using `oc rsync`.
8. In the MySQL pod, restore the database using the uploaded file, as per [this migration guide (step 6)](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/migrating_applications/database_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-database-applications-mysql).
9. Grant all privileges to your user on the application database by `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database> TO '<mysql_user>'@'%'` (Replace `<database>` and `<mysql_user>` appropriately.)
10. Exit the MySQL CLI on the pod, and run `mysql_upgrade -u root` in the shell.

Comment: If a pod will not start, you can also scale down the original so it doesn't interfere, and then use ``oc debug dc/appname`` to start up a pod from the same deployment configuration. Instead of running the application, it will leave you in an interactive shell with same volumes mounted in the pod. You could then run any commands, including starting the database or running management commands. This may avoid you needing to work out how to mount the volume into another pod.

Comment: I tried to create a dummy deployment but it is failed with exception: "Error: Error response from daemon: {"message":"create ea32962cc297331c2657101c829f8b35d92abb0b7c81f07b43e10ed4112ba77d: mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes/ea32962cc297331c2657101c829f8b35d92abb0b7c81f07b43e10ed4112ba77d: permission denied"}"